# How can I add a Bitcoin donation link to my website?

Tags: bitcoin

I figure something like a hyperlink + QR code would do the job, but I don't want to accidentally upload my private key. Is there a Bitcoin service that makes this easy to manage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a BitCoin receiving address, this can be done in your BitCoin software, then post that on your web site.

You can see an example of this on the [bitcoinfoundation.org](https://bitcoinfoundation.org/donate) web site.